# How to check if service spoolsv.exe is responding to requests without printing?

Tags: windows, printing

My friend's server has some problem with spoolsv service. While he is searching for a problem source, we need to make periodic service checks and restart service if it stops responding. I suppose the source of a problem is faulty printer drivers, but that needs investigation.

The question is how to check if this service is ok without attempting to print something. How can we "ping" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've been having issues with a spooler service in this manner, I can usually tell if the spooler is up by checking for it in the task manager, looking in the Services MMC Snapin and finally, checking to see if you can open the printer properties...

If all three are true, it indicates that the spooler is able to receive requests.

Comment: I didn't mean any manual checking. I meant automatic checking.